# Info.plist couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, info.plist

My question is about getting this error when opening Info.plist file:

> Info.plist couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

when opening from vs for mac or xcode also, what could be wrong with tha plist file? here is my plist file so you can have a look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>10.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MovesaGarantias</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MovesaGarantias</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.MovesaGarantias</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Can we use your location at all times?</string>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Can we use your location when your app is being used?</string>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Can we use your location at all times?</string>
  <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Needs Calendar Permission</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-60@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-60@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-76</string>
        <string>Icon-76@2x</string>
        <string>Default</string>
        <string>Default@2x</string>
        <string>Default-568h@2x</string>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <string>Default-Portrait@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40@3x</string>
        <string>Icon-Small</string>
        <string>Icon-Small@2x</string>
        <string>Icon-Small@3x</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>   
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Error also says that the tag Key is unsopported on Xamarin vs for Mac.

Comment: this file successfully opened in my Visual Studio for Windows

Comment: Did it open without edition?

Comment: yes... but not in VS for Mac

Comment: Can't reproduce any issue. The plist file you have shown now is a valid plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have an array for a value, but no key on line 34:

```
  <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Needs Calendar Permission</string>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-60@2x</string>
```

Before the `<array>` tag, you need to have a `<key>Keyname</key>` entry.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it does make sense, changed it but for some reason it still shows same error.

Comment: Without seeing the edits, we can't tell you what went wrong. Did you put the `<key>Keyname</key>` between the `</string>` and `<array>` I mention above? I did that and it became valid again.

Comment: <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Needs Calendar Permission</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
 <array>
  <string>Icon-60@2x</string>
  <string>Icon-60@3x</string>

Comment: Why don't you edit the new file into your original question. What you wrote looks good, so maybe something else is going wrong at this point?

Comment: I've edited the file on the Original Question, thanks again.

Comment: It opens fine in both Xcode and Firefox for me. Firefox gave me better errors when testing the previous one, so maybe try opening it with that and see what it tells you.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the missing key

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've corrected your plist file, it is valid and opens just fine in Xcode:

[image]